# How do you create a home page without a file name or .HTML extension?

Tags: html, homepage, file-extension

When we make HTML pages, we generally save it with a `.htm` or `.htm`l extension. But most webpages on the internet have extensions like .com or .org, for example, `https://example.com`. How do these pages work?

Comment: `.org` in `en.wikipedia.org` is **NOT** an extension, please do not use this term, even if widely used. It is one of the label of the domain name, and since it is at the extreme right and since DNS is right to left writing basically, it is called the Top Level Domain or TLD for short.

Comment: On the web, filename extensions should not matter, if things are properly done. See "What to leave out" in https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI (but the whole document is a very good read)

Comment: you can use  .htaccess and URL rewriting. This is part of server configuration.you can't do it with only .html extension.Refer following site:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve this:

1. Create an `index.html` inside root folder of your hosting and open your domain ie. `http://example.com`, you can see the output from `index.html` on `http://example.com`
2. You can tell your server using `.htaccess` to display the desired file when someone opens your domain.

Answer (score -1):

Create your index.html file. You will see when you publish that it will say 'example.com/page.html'. To remove the .html you need to create a .htaccess file in your root folder. Within that .htaccess file paste this code:

```
#Removes file extentions from URL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

This also removes .php file extensions.

It's good to know that if you want HTTPS instead of HTTP, you also use the same .htaccess file for this.

Comment: This rewrite URLS with no periods that don't have a corresponding file in the file system to internally look for a `.php` file.   Otherwise for such URLs that do have a file, it adds a `.html` extension.  (Your `RewriteCond` only applies to the very next rule, not to both rules.)  These rewrite are very broken and nobody should be using them.  They also don't solve the whole problem.   They could allow some extensionless URLs to work, but they don't remove extensions from existing URLs or change any links within your site that contain URL extensions.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can say that, because when I use it on my websites it removes the .html and .php from the url. So it does work.

Comment: I would recommend changing the condition to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` and adding a second condition before the `.html` rule: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f`.  I think those would work, if you could test them and update your question.  It would also be ideal to include any code you have for redirecting away from the `.php` and `.html` URLs and to explain how you link in your pages.